# Java JAR will not execute on VSCode Codespace

Tags: java, jar, codespaces

After building my project's JAR with `jar cvfm Project.jar MANIFEST.MF -C bin/com/dacoder/project/ .`, my JAR would not execute, outputting `no main manifest attribute, in Project.jar`. I am working on a Codespace (no build tools, but a VSCode extension will build and execute the classes automatically)

Linking a manifest with my projects entry point does not seem to work, as it doesnt seem to detect a manifest even though `jar tf Project.jar` outputs all of my projects classes along with the manifest. (The manifest includes `Main-Class: com.dacoder.project.Project`)

For some reason, attempting to execute just the entry point class file (`java Project.class`) does not work (throws `ClassNotFoundException` unless I specify the classpath with `java -cp bin com.dacoder.project.Project`), however trying something similar with the JAR (`java -cp Project.jar com.dacoder.project.Project`) also outputs `ClassNotFoundException`, regardless of the specified classpath.

I made [a post on another forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24nlD.png) that did not get any answers if that answers any other questions.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: It looks like the `jar` command line was incorrect.  It should have been `jar cvfm Project.jar MANIFEST.MF -C bin/`.  (What you have done is to create a JAR with a directory structure that doesn't allow the classloader to find the classes properly.)

Comment: @StephenC Thank you so much, `java -cp Project.jar com.dacoder.project.Project` is executing now. I'm really new to Java and still a bit unsure why I must specify the entry point manually though, is it an issue with my directory structure?

Comment: *java -cp Project.jar com.dacoder.project.Project is executing now* You shouldn't need `-cp` if your manifest is right. Just `java -jar Project.jar`

Comment: @g00se `java -jar Project.jar` outputs `no main manifest attribute, in Project.Jar`, my manifest.mf is `Main-Class: com.dacoder.project.Project`

Comment: Earlier on your file name was given in uppercase. Anyway there's something wrong. There's no need to create such a file anyway just do this: `jar cvfe Project.jar com.dacoder.project.Project -C bin .` Then `java -jar Project.jar` will work

Comment: @g00se that works great! Thank you so much.